# Adding blade section programmatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For example, assume I am pushing script to `pageScripts` section like blow.

```
@section('pageScripts')
    <script src="{{URL :: asset('assets/some-script-1.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL :: asset('assets/some-script-2.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

I can simply create this section in my blade template specific to the route. The problem is it would load only when the route is called. Or the solution is to add it in layout permanently.

The problem I encounter is, when I am creating additional packages. I need to add some scripts that is always loaded with the application. I wonder if I can push some content into the blade section programmatically into any predefined section (pageScripts) in my application's core. Any feasible ideas are welcome. Thanks guys!

Comment: So you want to add some scripts for example from a controller or provider, not from a blade template?

Comment: Exactly. Yes, from the provider.

Comment: This seems like a package that does what you need https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-assets/wiki

Comment: It looks not works for me.  Using this one, i need to alter the core applications layout.blade template. What I am expecting is to append some script without altering the layout file and completely through the new package. Might be with Provider. If there is some onDispatch event available in Laravel, that can be cought and modify the output, that would be great.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this in any way without modifying the layout file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but it sounds like you could solve this with named stacks? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#stacks The link is to 5.3 but they exist in 5.2 as well.

Comment: @JoelHinz I will try. or else need to find an alternative way. thanks.